# Django: use slugify for detail url

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I want to use slugs in my details urls but when I want to acces to a url like this:

localhost:8000/movie-1

Send me this error

```
Value Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'pelicula'
```

Here is my model:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Movie(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='nombre', max_length=250)

    @property
    def slug(self):
        return '{}'.format(slugify(self.name, allow_unicode=True))
```

My url:

```
url(
    regex=r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
    view=views.DetailMovie.as_view(),
    name='movie'
),
```

And finally my view:

```
class DetailMovie(DetailView):

    model = Movie
    pk_url_kwarg = "slug"
    context_object_name = "movie"
    template_name = "detail_movie.html"
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're having two problems:

- Don't use `pk_url_kwarg` for this, for default, the detail view will look for an argument called `slug` on the view arguments, if you change the name of the argument, use `slug_url_kwarg`.
- You don't have an `slug` field in your model, you are defining a property, that's not a field, so the Django ORM can't query over it, you're using that property to automatically create the slug from the model's name field, and that's cool, but you can't use it to query so what's the point.

A better model would be like this:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='nombre', max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name, allow_unicode=True)
        return super(Movie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This way you have the field, and the field will update itself every time the model is saved, and on top of it, your view doesn't need any additional customization:

```
class DetailMovie(DetailView):
    model = Movie
    context_object_name = "movie"
    template_name = "detail_movie.html"
```

Answer (score 2):

This won't work. The slug needs to be an actual field saved on the model, otherwise there'd be no way for the database to look up the item based on its slug.